# File not found at path: file.xlsx

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using Maatwebsite package for inserting some data into the Database by uploading an Excel file.

So here is my routes:

```
Route::get('import-form', 'Olympiad\OlympiadExamExecutionController@importForm');
Route::post('import-form', 'Olympiad\OlympiadExamExecutionController@executeImport')->name('addcutsom.execution');
```

And here is my Controller:

```
use App\Imports\CustomExamImport;
use App\Olympiad\OlympiadExamExecution;
use Excel;

public function importForm()
{
    return view('import');
}

public function executeImport(Request $request)
{
    Excel::import(new CustomExamImport, $request->file);
    return "Records are imported";
}
```

And here is the `CustomExamImport`:

```
class CustomExamImport implements ToModel
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $user_id = DB::table('members')->where('mbr_national_code', $row[3])->value('mbr_usr_id');
        return new OlympiadExamExecution([
            'oex_correct_answer_count' => $row[7],
            'oex_wrong_answer_count' => $row[8],
            'oex_no_answer_count' => $row[9],
            'oex_score' => $row[10],
        ]);
    }
}
```

And this is the Blade form:

```
<form action="{{ route('addcutsom.execution') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <label class="control-label">Upload File:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="file" type="file">

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">ثبت</button>  
</form>
```

Now when I try to upload an Excel file from my computer, I get this error:

### **File not found at path: file.xlsx**

So what's going wrong out there?

Comment: move the file to your upload path before processing it then delete it afterward. processing it in the tmp folder cant lead to errors.

Comment: @N69S Can you explain it as answer please, I'm really stuck with this!

Comment: first try `$request->file('file')->getPath()` instead of `$request->file` and you should try to move the file anyway before hand https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: @N69S Call to a member function getPath() on null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the error

> Call to a member function getPath() on null

because the file was not uploaded.

Change your form to inlcude `enctype` to upload files

```
<form action="{{ route('addcutsom.execution') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

you can find mode details on the attribute [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/4369919)